# date time format issue in .net hours like 00:00:00

Tags: vb.net

I have a log function,
We pass in the log name and a message and we open the file and append a text to the end of it.
for some reason, the hour format isn't getting logged correctly, any ideas?

It is logging the correct date but the time is being logged as `00:00:00`

```
Public Shared Sub WriteLog(filename As String, detailToLog As String)
        Dim logPath As String = String.Format(Application.StartupPath & "\logs\")
        Dim filePath As String = String.Format(logPath & filename & " - {0}.txt", DateTime.Today.ToString("dd-MM-yyyy"))

        If (Not System.IO.Directory.Exists(logPath)) Then
            System.IO.Directory.CreateDirectory(logPath)
        End If

        Select Case filename
            Case "Error"
                File.AppendAllText(filePath, String.Format(DateTime.Today.ToString("dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm:ss") & " Error: " & detailToLog & vbNewLine))

            Case "Email"
                File.AppendAllText(filePath, String.Format(DateTime.Today.ToString("dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm:ss") & " Email sent to: " & detailToLog & vbNewLine))

            Case "Login"
                File.AppendAllText(filePath, String.Format(DateTime.Today.ToString("dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm:ss") & " User logged in: " & detailToLog & vbNewLine))

            Case "FacialRecognition"
                File.AppendAllText(filePath, String.Format(DateTime.Today.ToString("dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm:ss") & " User Identified: " & detailToLog & vbNewLine))

            Case "SQL"
                File.AppendAllText(filePath, String.Format(DateTime.Today.ToString("dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm:ss") & " SQL query : " & detailToLog & vbNewLine))
        End Select

    End Sub
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is that you are using `DateTime.Today`. That is specifically the current date with the time zeroed. What you should be using is `DateTime.Now`, which is the current date AND time. The implementation of `DateTime.Today` actually returns `DateTime.Now.Date`.

Comment: I wasn't aware, this worked perfectly for me. thank you

Answer (score 0):

Exactly as jmcilhinney said, `.Today` returns only a date, where on `.Now` returns DateAndTime, you can also get DateAndTime in ISO format YYYYMMDDHHMMSS using `Now.ToUniversalTime()`